# Improve HD graphics performance

Tags: 16.04, games, intel-graphics

I got a Celeron N3150 SoC (on a passively cooled Biostar N3150NH ITX mobo) with integrated HD graphics that should run older games just fine. But the performance is lacking especially considering that I'm running dual channel RAM. On another system with the same SoC and single channel RAM I got better performance. Is there something I can do to tweak it? [Torchlight 2](http://store.steampowered.com/app/200710/Torchlight_II/) is basically unplayable in 1080p but it shouldn't be.

edit: strangely I was offered the option to install a proprietary driver which I did. Will check performance. Any info on what kind of driver this is? It just says: "processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs from intel-microcode (proprietary)"

Comment: The microcode won't help anything. In some cases it actaully causes lots of problems.

Comment: Also, does it perform as you would expect on Windows?